# vuetify select show selected value before input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I use Vuetify and I have select like this:

```
<v-select
  v-model="gender.value"
     :items="gender.items"
     label="Gender"
     :solo="true"
     append-icon="">
</v-select>
....
data: () => ({
   gender: {
      value: null,
      items: ['male', 'female']
   }
})
```

and for some reason when I select some value it shows it like this: https://gyazo.com/10129a3b111947c04b7db3f4212ad78b but I want it to be inside the input field. What I'm doing wrong? In the Vuetify docs I even did not found select which display selected value like that. Thanks!

Comment: can you try to put your code in codesand for debug?

Comment: I probably found the issue, on their site, it also separates from the input, the selection is separate div. So looks, like I broke CSS, I add `position: absolute` and it's okay now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just mess up CSS, I add `position:absolute` to the div which hold selected value and now it's fine